# TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get a "TypeError in Activities#member - can't convert Symbol into Integer"

I would say that 95% of my records work fine but I have a couple that keep tripping this error. Where do I start to look at this problem.

Here is the code I am working with:

.html.erb page

```
<div id="listing-gallery">
<ul id="listing-slides">
    <% listing.slides.each_with_index do |slide, i| %>
        <%= content_tag :li, :id => "slide#{i}", :class => (i == 0) ? "active" : "" do %>
            <%= image_tag slide[:large] %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<ul id="listing-slide-thumbs">
    <% if listing.slides.count > 1 %>
        <% listing.slides.each_with_index do |slide, i| %>
            <%= content_tag :li, :class => (((i+1)%4 == 0) ? "last" : "") do %>
            <%= content_tag :a, :href => "#slide#{i}" do %>
                    <span class="hover"></span>
                    <%= image_tag slide[:thumb] %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

.activities_controller.rb

```
def member
# Assign attrs if venue exists
if @member.nil? || @member.venue.nil?
  redirect_to activities_path
else
  if @member.venue.attrs.count > 0
    # match_by_type can be found in the ApplicationHelper
    @attrs = match_by_type @member.venue.attrs
  else
    @attrs = nil
  end

  unless @member.venue.nil?
    unless @member.venue.attrs.nil?
      @member_rentals = @member.venue.attrs.all_by_type("Rentals")
    end
  end  
end
end
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I guess I am not sure why my question would be downgraded. I have been RESEARCHING this for two days and can't find any sort of answer that would clue me find out how to solve this. If I need to post more information then tell me what else you need rather then downgrading me.

Comment: line 5 of the .html.erb page.

Answer (score 0):

see `<%= image_tag slide[:large] %>` and `<%= image_tag slide[:thumb] %>`

what `image` attribute for `slide`?

If `image` is attribute for `slide`, I think such as :

`<%= image_tag slide.image.url(:large) %>`

or if usinng carrierwave

`<%= image_tag slide.image_url(:large).to_s %>`

By the way, I don't see `listing.slides` on `action member`

Comment: Oh my word... Anonymousxxx I was missing the the listing.slides and that was screwing everything up. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Sometimes you look at something too hard and it is right there.